# How to bring a Kendo UI Menu in front of a kendo (draggable) window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, window, kendo-ui

I want to use a menu bar at the top of every page of my asp.net mvc4 web application with Kendo UI. One of my web pages is a combination of multiple draggable windows of Kendo UI. When a have a window placed right under the menu, the menu opens behind the window. I've set the window to non modal, but it still doesn't work.
Is this possible in Kendo UI ASP.NET mvc 4 with razor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply higher z-index to the menu. If using Razor the following should work:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "position: relative; z-index: 11000" })
)
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/uwujih/1/edit